# how can i install ICU 59 on xampp v3.2.2 and PHP 7.1.9?

Tags: php, symfony, xampp, icu, intl

i using xampp v3.2.2 and PHP 7.1.9 on windows 10 x64, that xampp version comes with ICU 57

I need to upgrade it to 59 (request from symfony 3.3.10), so i downloaded ICU59 and copied all ICU*59*.dll to php directory and Apache bin directory, but it's not recognized.
php info still show ICU 57. if need download php_intl.dll new version. where i can download later version.

Does the "php_intl.dll" have to be upgraded ?

Thanks

Comment: I am confronted with the same problem. Did you find a solution yet? It seems you have to compile php from source in order to pick up the ICU*59*.dlls.

Comment: There are no solutions for this error unless xampp release new version. Ignore this warning and continue developing projects. Good luck for your project.